# Jquery animate, прерывание анимации

Tags: jquery, javascript

День добрый, озадачился следующим моментом, остановить анимацию выполняющуюся к примеру 7 секунд, и после возобновить её только не с семью секундами а за минусом того времени которое прошло до последнего прерывания анимации, то есть фактически вся анимация должна выполняться 7 секунд,  а не 21 секунду к примеру если три раза её прерывать 
Пока что дописался до  этого:

```
var interval = 7000; // исходный интервал на выполнение анимации
var a, all = 0, init =0, lefT=0; // определяем переменные
anim(interval);

$('#bar').hover(function () { //на hover 
    $(this).stop();
    init += Math.round(new Date() - a); // суммарное время всех прерываний
    lefTime = interval - init; // оставшееся время
}, function () { // on hover out
    anim(lefTime);
});

function anim(interval) { // сама функция анимирования
    a = new Date(); //
    $('#bar').animate({
        width: 500
    }, interval);
}
```

Какое еще более простое решение возможно!?

Answer (score 1):

В документации по jQuery есть замечательный пример остановки анимации

http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/